# Protecting and Hiding Columns same as "Very Hidden" Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide, spreadsheet-protection

I am trying to hide some columns and prevent the user to have any access to them; while they can edit other parts of the sheet.

What I am seeking is something like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

So user cannot see them. I am aware that one option is adding another sheet and move those columns to there and hide that one sheet; but as I am working on a relatively large data-set and it has a standard format within the company, I prefer not to do so.

I already tried locking the columns and protecting the sheets and checking all the boxes except the ones for selecting locked cells, inserting and deleting both rows and columns (code below).

```
Function VeryHideColumn(myColumn As Range)

    myColumn.Locked = True
    myColumn.FormulaHidden = True
    myColumn.Hidden = True
    'myColumn.Hidden = xlVeryHidden 'I already tried this

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowSorting:= _
        True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

End Function
```

This is the problem: users still can select a range containing these hidden and locked columns and unhide them. Is there any method or trick like `VeryHidden` for sheets available for ranges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Original Answer:

If the users don't need to format the columns and rows, then there's a work around for this:

If `AllowFormattingColumns` and `AllowFormattingRows` were false (which is default if not stated), then user would not be able to hide or unhide them.

#### Update:

Function below "very hides" only the columns based on above idea;

```
Function VeryHideColumn(myColumn As Range)
'By M--, April 2017

    myColumn.Locked = True
    myColumn.Hidden = xlVeryHidden
    myColumn.FormulaHidden = True

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
        AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True _
    , AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

End Function
```

If you want to very hide the rows, then set the `AllowFormattingRows` to false.