# VBA Excel trying to make the column "very hidden"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hid some columns in my worksheets. I want to have them invisible for all external users. Thety cannot be aware, that the hidden column exist at all.

I found something, which can help me made them "Very hidden" likewise we can set for a whole sheets.

Unfortunately my approach doesn't work so far.

I have got a function, which should be right, but to be fair I don't know how to use it properly.

```
  Sub Overheadhidden()
  Columns("V:W").VeryHideColumn
  End Sub


  Function VeryHideColumn(myColumn As Range)
  'By M--, April 2017

   myColumn.Locked = True
   myColumn.Hidden = xlVeryHidden
   myColumn.FormulaHidden = True

   ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True _
  , AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

  End Function
```

It comes from this solution:

[Protecting and Hiding Columns same as "Very Hidden" Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686154/protecting-and-hiding-columns-same-as-very-hidden-sheets)

Is there ANY possible way to make the columns very hidden?

Comment: Can you not transfer the columns to a separate worksheet then hide and password protect that worksheet?

Comment: No, It would be vital to keep everything in the same worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

`.VeryHideColumn()` is not a method or a property. You need to call it as a function:

```vb
Sub Overheadhidden()

  Call VeryHideColumn(Columns("V:W"))

End Sub
```

I will also add that I would recommend this being a `Sub` rather than a `Function` simply because the general rule of thumb is to use `Function` when you want to return something. With your code you are simply giving it a task, so below is a bit better:

```vb
Sub VeryHideColumn(myColumn As Range)

   myColumn.Locked = True
   myColumn.Hidden = xlVeryHidden
   myColumn.FormulaHidden = True

   ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False, _
       AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
       AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
       AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error:

Unable to set locked property for a range of class.

Comment: @MKR I have tested and this is working on my system.

Comment: @MKR the error happens when you run the code more than once. You will need to reverse the locked property before running again.

Comment: I found a slightly different way for it. Thank you very much for your help.